# How to get server element id on click event in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have server elements:

```
<custom:MenuItem ID="buttonAdd" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server"/>
<custom:MenuItem ID="buttonDelete" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server"/>
```

I created method for "Click" event:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   /*Solution of problem*/
}
```

I want get element id that clicked in this method.

Comment: in debug mode, check sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
   if(menuItem!=null)
   {
    var prop = menuItem./*any property you want here*/
   }
}
```

Comment: I Can't get access to ID with help of "menuItem.ID" because ID property is absent.

Comment: But ID property exists for all server elements. I don't know why I can't use "menuItem.ID".

Comment: have you created menuitem?? if yes please provide code for the same

Answer (score 0):

use this

this is to find menuitem that can be clicked:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   MenuItem b = (MenuItem )sender;
}
```